# How can I reference the value of a final static field in the class?

Tags: java, documentation, javadoc

Using JavaDoc, how can I reference the value of a final static field in the class?

I want the `???` in this example replaced by the value of the field `STATIC_FIELD`.

```
/**
 * This is a simple class with only one static field with the value ???.
 */
public class Simple {

    /**
     * We can reference the value with {@value} here, 
     * but how do we reference it in the class JavaDoc?
     */
    public static final String STATIC_FIELD = "simple static field";

}
```

Answer (score 248, accepted):

Do you mean `{@value #STATIC_FIELD}`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I edited my question in order to make it clear. It would be perfect if the value of the field would be shown in the JavaDoc directly...

Comment: can this be referenced in other classes as well? when I tried to do that it didn't work out for me.

Comment: it is always the # :)

Comment: @RajithGunHewage, you can reference it from another class like `{@value com.package.other.Clazz#STATIC_FIELD}`

Comment: Just in case, for non-primitive constants it will be {@link #STATIC_NON_PRIMITIVE_FIELD}

Comment: @Sean, as a matter of fact, it should be by using {@link com.package.other.Clazz#STATIC_FIELD}

Comment: @Yuriy That's not correct. `{@link ...}` provides a link to the Javadoc of the named field, which in turn does not provide the value. `{@value ...}` provides the actual value, which is what was asked for. 'Non-primitive' has exactly nothing to do with it. See the example of `{@value ...}` in the Javadoc tool documentation, for instance, which uses `java.lang.String`.

Comment: thanks for pointing out my mistake...appreciated, sincerely