# Is it possible to use String values to populate a doc comment?

Tags: java, comments, javadoc

I'm wondering if it's possible to tie the text of a doc comment of a method to a String value in code. For example:

```
String myHelloMethodDocComment = "This is a doc comment. \n @param arg1";

{Some sort of magic, maybe here maybe somewhere else}
public void printHello(String world){
    System.out.print("Hello " + world);
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    printHello("world");
}
```

In this example, should I generate a javadoc or mouse over the line printHello("world") in main using an editor that supports them, I would ideally want to see

"This is a doc comment.

**param** arg1"

In the mouse-over window.

Is this possible, maybe using something in the new Java 8 [doctree api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/javac/tree/com/sun/source/doctree/package-summary.html) that I just haven't found?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of [How can I reference the value of a final static field in the class javadoc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868991/how-can-i-reference-the-value-of-a-final-static-field-in-the-class-javadoc)

Comment: Thanks. That wasn't exactly what I was going for but it's close enough for my needs. Using {@value} I can't have the string value being read as if it were a doc comment itself, so you can't use any annotations. Perhaps there's another way of doing it that would allow for that.